# There is 1 error : an error occurred while creating your account Prestashop New Registration

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

i just move to another hosting and restore files and DB from backed up files to new hosting,
everything works fine except new registration part,
i am getting this error:

There is 1 error :

```
an error occurred while creating your account
```

i compared both new and old DB , 100% same, 
the only things that i have to mention Prestashop version is 1.3 and now hosted on eHost Hosting , current php version is 5.6 and it's latest version of MySql

Please advise to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue with Prestashop 1.4. We moved from one hosting to another. And when a client tried to register the following error popped up: An error occurred while creating your account..

In our case we came from MySQL and went to MariaDB. In the configuration STRICT_TRANS_TABLES was turned on. And by turning this off the issue was solved.